Using Python 3.9, How do I get in MS excel ALL physical addresses from the URL -> https://www.tamoil.ch/en/store-locator
I would like to get all physical addresses in MS-excel from this url [https://www.tamoil.ch/en/store-locator].  The spreadsheet only has a header, but no output from the code.
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# Send a GET request to the website
url = "https://www.tamoil.ch/en/store-locator"

response = requests.get(url)

# Parse the HTML content
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

# Find all elements containing store information
store_elements = soup.find_all('div', class_='store-element')

# Extract addresses
addresses = []
for store in store_elements:
    address = store.find('p', class_='address').text.strip()
    addresses.append(address)

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Address': addresses})

# Save to Excel file
excel_file = 'tamoil_addresses.xlsx'
df.to_excel(excel_file, index=False)

print(f"Addresses saved to {excel_file}")


There is no  element with a "store-element" class on that page

Wonderful.  I saw the Lat/Long data is available. can it be included in the output?

Can you check this out if this is what you are looking for?
import requests
import pandas as pd
from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)

url = "https://www.tamoil.ch/page-data/en/store-locator/page-data.json" #address and location in JSON format
resp = requests.get(url, verify=False)
data = resp.json()['result']['data']['allStation']['nodes']

slug_r = []
name_r = []
lat_r = []
lng_r = []
street_r = []
zip_code_r = []
city_r = []
phone_r = []

for i in data:
    slug_r.append(i['slug'])
    name_r.append(i['name'])
    lat_r.append(i['lat'])
    lng_r.append(i['lng'])
    street_r.append(i['street'])
    zip_code_r.append(i['zip'])
    city_r.append(i['city']['name'])
    phone_r.append(i['phone_1'])
    print(f"-----------------------\nSLUG:   {i['slug']}\nNAME:   {i['name']}\nLATITUDE:   {i['lat']}\nLONITUDE:   {i['lng']}\nSTREET ADDRESS:   {i['street']}\nPHONE:   {i['phone_1']}\nZIP CODE:   {i['zip']}\nCITY:   {i['city']['name']}")

data_dict = {
    'SLUG': slug_r,
    'NAME': name_r,
    'LATITUDE': lat_r,
    'LONGITUDE': lng_r,
    'STREET': street_r,
    'ZIP CODE': zip_code_r,
    'PHONE': phone_r,
    'CITY': city_r
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
df.to_excel('Address.xlsx', index=False)

I used their page-data (JSON) endpoint to grab all these addresses.
Let me know if I missed something based on your question

Thank you. this answers it all exquisitely !

All the information you need can be found here which means that you only have to parse a JSON document to get the required results.
import requests
import pandas as pd

filename = "tamoil.xlsx"
url = "https://www.tamoil.ch/page-data/en/store-locator/page-data.json"
keylist = ["name", "street", "zip", "lat", "lng"]

def make_dict(node):
    return {key.title(): node.get(key, "n/a") for key in keylist}

with requests.get(url) as response:
    response.raise_for_status()
    data = response.json()
    addresses = [make_dict(n) for n in data["result"]["data"]["allStation"]["nodes"]]
    pd.DataFrame(addresses).to_excel(filename, index=False)
    if __debug__:
        for address in addresses:
            print(address)

Output:
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Basel Aéroport', 'Street': 'Parkplatz 11 Aéroport', 'Zip': '4030', 'Lat': 47.598756, 'Lng': 7.537273}
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Bellwald', 'Street': 'Fuergangen', 'Zip': '3997', 'Lat': 46.41086, 'Lng': 8.151533}
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Commugny', 'Street': 'Rte de Genève 19', 'Zip': '1291', 'Lat': 46.315748, 'Lng': 6.174669}
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Flawil', 'Street': 'St.Galler-Strasse 144', 'Zip': '9230', 'Lat': 47.411974, 'Lng': 9.201063}
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Glarus', 'Street': 'Buchholzstrasse 44', 'Zip': '8750', 'Lat': 47.049127, 'Lng': 9.064221}
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Grandson', 'Street': 'Rue de Neuchâtel 43 / CP91', 'Zip': '1422', 'Lat': 46.815365, 'Lng': 6.652367}
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Hermance', 'Street': "564, rte D'Hermance", 'Zip': '1248', 'Lat': 46.302417, 'Lng': 6.246586}
{'Name': "TAMOIL L'Orient", 'Street': '20, rue du Pont-Neuf', 'Zip': '1341', 'Lat': 46.603372, 'Lng': 6.235358}
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Le Châble (Le Cotterg)', 'Street': 'Le Cotterg', 'Zip': '1934', 'Lat': 46.087245, 'Lng': 7.206818}
{'Name': 'TAMOIL Le Pont', 'Street': 'Sur les Quais 39', 'Zip': '1342', 'Lat': 46.666977, 'Lng': 6.329645}


This is excellent but is only 10 location and partially answers the data part.  How could be output be extracted in ms excel format?

@James Please feed me the full solution. Don't make me think!

@James The answer only prints the first 10 items (note the slice) for brevity. The dataframe function to_excel() creates the MS Excel file. The entire list of 235 addresses will be in the Excel file

hey @James just remove the [:10] and the rest will work accordingly

Thank you very much indeed. This works like a clock, perfect!  Thank you!
